# Processing Amazon MWS Feed Responses

Tags: amazon-web-services, jaxb, amazon-mws

We set up a system for processing Amazon feeds for a variety of customers. This is working for a lot of customers and we successfully process feeds like this:

```
<AmazonEnvelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd">
    <Header>
        <DocumentVersion>1.02</DocumentVersion>
        <MerchantIdentifier>REDACTED_8055</MerchantIdentifier>
    </Header>
    <MessageType>ProcessingReport</MessageType>
    <Message>
        <MessageID>1</MessageID>
        <ProcessingReport>
            <DocumentTransactionID>1016539</DocumentTransactionID>
            <StatusCode>Complete</StatusCode>
            <ProcessingSummary>
                <MessagesProcessed>218</MessagesProcessed>
                <MessagesSuccessful>218</MessagesSuccessful>
                <MessagesWithError>0</MessagesWithError>
                <MessagesWithWarning>0</MessagesWithWarning>
            </ProcessingSummary>
        </ProcessingReport>
    </Message>
</AmazonEnvelope>
```

However, one customer is getting back a feed response like this:

```
<AmazonEnvelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd">
    <Header>
        <DocumentVersion>3.00</DocumentVersion>
        <MerchantIdentifier>REDACTED_43183</MerchantIdentifier>
    </Header>
    <MessageType>ProcessingReport</MessageType>
    <Message>
        <MessageID>1</MessageID>
        <ProcessingReport>
            <ProcessingReportType>Inventory</ProcessingReportType>
            <DocumentTransactionID>10460738</DocumentTransactionID>
            <Summary MarketplaceName="All">
               <StatusCode>Complete</StatusCode>
               <ProcessingSummary>
                   <MessagesProcessed>1</MessagesProcessed>
                   <MessagesSuccessful>1</MessagesSuccessful>
                   <MessagesWithError>0</MessagesWithError>
                   <MessagesWithWarning>0</MessagesWithWarning>
               </ProcessingSummary>
            </Summary>
        </ProcessingReport>
    </Message>
</AmazonEnvelope>
```

Which does not unsuccessfully unmarshal. Note the subtle differences: DocumentVersion is different, and the processingSummary is embedded inside of a Summary tag which the schema is not expecting. The latter kills the JAXB Unmarshalling process. I can't find any documentation on why this happens and was hoping someone here had come across this before.

I can't even tell JAXB to ignore unknown elements because I need the ProcessingSummary and it's buried under the strange "Summary" tag.

Does anyone know why one customer would get one type of feed response and another would get a different one?

Comment: So, what is your question, exactly? Why does Amazon deliver a different XML to one of the customers? It's quite obvious that this is a different schema so no surprize JAXB can't unmarshal 3.00 with 1.02 classes.

Comment: Yes, my question is, "why does Amazon deliver different XML to different customers?" I'll edit the question to reflect that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amazon's seller pro accounts exist in different versions. Sellers that have been with Amazon for a long time with special negotiated rates may have legacy accounts that were never upgraded to the latest API. All I had to was contact Amazon on the seller's behalf to have their account upgraded.

In this situation the seller was still able to keep the lucrative negotiated rates that they had with Amazon but I cannot guarantee that will always be the case.

Answer (score 1):

I know this isn't much of an answer, but based on the little I've had a chance to work through some of the marketplaces -- specifically China -- behave a little differently for different requests, in that they might have different capabilities or required information.  The following link may help point you in a better direction:

http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/feeds/Feeds_Overview.html#Feeds_EU_Global_Seller

I agree that it's strange that the same request would yield different results.  I've only used the [.NET client library for Feeds so far](https://developer.amazonservices.com/gp/mws/api.html/192-0285089-4377125?ie=UTF8&group=bde&section=feeds&version=latest), not manually parsing XML, but I did have a problem with error deserialization when submitting to the wrong service url.  After looking through the sourcecode (link above) I noticed that they're using two variants of regex matching to try to grab error code/message after failing to deserialize to an "expected" ErrorResponse object.  Turns out because I was accidentally making requests to the Orders endpoint (rather than the Feeds endpoint), the error XML was subtly different and so didn't even match up to the regex, and thus I wasn't even getting a useful error message back.

I mention all this because:

1. What marketplace is getting different results?  Could you be sending to the wrong endpoint?
2. Maybe as a fallback to using JAXB you could also use regex or xpath or string-matching to grab the relevant section.

Comment: Hey thanks for your feedback. I actually heard back from Amazon on this and the answer is something different. I will post the details now.